# PHP if substr not catching a certain phrase

Tags: php

I am using the PHP function `imap_open` to get emails into a MySQL database.

I am using this PHP code to check the subject, checking the *RE:* and *#* work fine, but checking if the subject is *Read:* doesn't.

I have tried echoing `substr($subject, 7,5);` which displays the 5 digits of the subject which is what I want but its not working  in the if statement

```
if(strtolower(substr($subject,0,3)) == 're:')
{
    $ticketnumber = substr($subject, 5,5);
}
elseif(strtolower(substr($subject,0,1)) == '#')
{
    $ticketnumber = substr($subject, 1,5);
}
elseif(strtolower(substr($subject,0,5)) == 'Read:')
{
    $ticketnumber = substr($subject, 7,5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strtolower and then comparing string with a capital letter.

Should be

```
elseif(strtolower(substr($subject,0,5)) == 'read:')
{
    $ticketnumber = substr($subject, 7,5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, strtolower is messing up your comparison.

Try something like this if you don't want to worry about case:

```
elseif(strcasecmp(substr($subject,0,5), 'read:') == 0)
{
    $ticketnumber = substr($subject, 7,5);
}
```

[strcasecmp](http://www.php.net/strcasecmp)